# how to apply css classname hashes to html template?

Tags: webpack, css-loader

I'm trying to build a website using webpack.

If using the rules with localIdentName the classnames get renamed, but in my html they stay the same.

```
    module: {

        rules: [
            
            { 
                test: /\.css$/i,

                use: [
                    
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { loader: 'css-loader'} // options: { modules: { localIdentName: '[hash:base64:12]', }}
                ]
            },
        ],
    }
```

I'm loading the html template through:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './static/index.html' }),
```